# Weight Painting symmetry Issue

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

I made our a custom rig. When I painted these lips on the left, my eyelashes stayed red, I tried to subtract the eyelashes, but it did not show anything.

Sometimes I subtract on the left eyelash then subtract on the right to get rid of anything red when click on the right lip, and then back again to click on the left lip, it is still red! I did turn symmetry on, but it not working, they are not matched. this is confusing. Does anybody know how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the X symmetry option on, which mirror the weight painting, and also the *Auto Normalize* option on, which keep some parts red even though you try to substract them:

[image]